# How to make a mountainous area flat in Blender?

Tags: blender, modeling

how can i make this selected area flat and not mountainous?
[Image of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoOVF.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://blender.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 0):

Scale selected faces to 0 on Z axis. You can do that by selecting scale operator `S` then clicking `Z` to operate on Z axis only a than clicking `0` to se Z scale as zero.